# nm symbol names slightly different

Tags: c++, linker-errors, symbols, nm

I have an undefined symbol name in one shared lib:

`U _ZN5Daetk5Petsc3Sys10catchErrorEj`

In the shared lib that should resolve this, the symbol name is different in its last character:

`000000000008c65e T _ZN5Daetk5Petsc3Sys10catchErrorEb`

These two shared libs are compiled with the same stack (gcc-7.3.0).

Why would this happen? How can this be resolved?

Here is the relevant code for the dependent lib header.h.

```
extern "C" {
typedef struct
{
  PyObject_HEAD
  Daetk::Petsc::Sys* petscSys;
} DaetkPetscSys;
}
```

The dependent lib source.cpp.

```
extern "C" {
static PyObject* 
DaetkPetscSys_catchError(DaetkPetscSys *self, PyObject *args)
{
  bool error;
  if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"b",&error)) return NULL;
  return Py_BuildValue("b",self->petscSys->catchError(error));
}
}
```

The resolving lib header.h (cleaned).

```
namespace Daetk {
namespace Petsc {
class Sys
{  
public:
  Sys();
  virtual ~Sys();
  bool catchError(bool error);
};
} } //Petsc::Daetk
```

The resolving lib source.cpp (cleaned).

```
bool Daetk::Petsc::Sys::catchError(bool error)
{
  using namespace cc;
  int thisVal=error;
  int result=error;
  MPI_Allreduce(&thisVal,&result,1,MPI_INT,MPI_LOR,PETSC_COMM_WORLD);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: There must be some difference between the declaration in the caller and the definition in the library.

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: Provide the mangled names to the tool `c++filt` to see what they mean. It looks like the parameter type of `catchError` changed.

Comment: '$ c++filt _ZN5Daetk5Petsc3Sys10catchErrorEb Daetk::Petsc::Sys::catchError(bool)

Comment: $ c++filt _ZN5Daetk5Petsc3Sys10catchErrorEj
Daetk::Petsc::Sys::catchError(unsigned int)

Comment: @aschepler. That gave me enough to know how to fix it. Thanks! Did not know c++filt even existed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `<stdbool.h>` was giving some odd `_Bool is not a type` issue in hdf5 when one of its headers was being included in a Cython compilation. As a hack, I commented out the `<stdbool.h>` include and redefined bool as unsigned int. This is the source of the symbol name mismatch issue.